# Replace transitive dependency of Gradle plugin

Tags: gradle, jsch, gradle-plugin, jgit, axion-release-plugin

The [axion-release](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/pl.allegro.tech.build.axion-release) Gradle plugin has a dependency on the unmaintained [com.jcraft:jsch:0.1.55](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.jcraft/jsch/0.1.55) lib.  The [com.github.mwiede:jsch](https://github.com/mwiede/jsch) fork is a drop-in replacement for jcraft jsch providing the same namespace.  How can I replace the plugin's dependency?

[image]

This does not appear to work:

```
buildscript {
  dependencies {
    classpath('pl.allegro.tech.build:axion-release-plugin:1.14.2') {
      exclude group: 'com.jcraft', module: 'jsch'
    }
  } 
  configurations.classpath {
    resolutionStrategy {
      force 'com.github.mwiede:jsch:0.2.4'
    }
  }
}
```

This will remove com.jcraft.jsch from the classpath but that does not replace it with the maintained lib:

```
buildscript {
  configurations.classpath {
    resolutionStrategy {
      exclude group: 'com.jcraft', module: 'jsch'
    }
  }
}
```

This also does not work

```
buildscript {
  dependencies {
    classpath('pl.allegro.tech.build:axion-release-plugin:1.14.2') {
      exclude group: 'com.jcraft', module: 'jsch'
    }
    classpath 'com.github.mwiede:jsch:0.2.4'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried substitution

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath "pl.allegro.tech.build:axion-release-plugin:1.14.2"
    }


    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.dependencySubstitution {
            substitute module("com.jcraft:jsch") using module("com.github.mwiede:jsch:0.2.4") because "of https://stackoverflow.com/q/74355649/2290153"
        }
    }

}
```

and `buildEnvironment` gives:

```
classpath
\--- pl.allegro.tech.build:axion-release-plugin:1.14.2
     +--- org.eclipse.jgit:org.eclipse.jgit:5.13.1.202206130422-r
     |    +--- com.googlecode.javaewah:JavaEWAH:1.1.13
     |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.30
     +--- org.eclipse.jgit:org.eclipse.jgit.ssh.jsch:5.13.1.202206130422-r
     |    +--- org.eclipse.jgit:org.eclipse.jgit:5.13.1.202206130422-r (*)
     |    +--- com.jcraft:jsch:0.1.55 -> com.github.mwiede:jsch:0.2.4
     |    +--- com.jcraft:jzlib:1.1.1
     |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.30
     +--- com.jcraft:jsch:0.1.55 -> com.github.mwiede:jsch:0.2.4
     +--- com.jcraft:jsch.agentproxy.core:0.0.9
     +--- com.jcraft:jsch.agentproxy.jsch:0.0.9
     |    +--- com.jcraft:jsch:0.1.49 -> com.github.mwiede:jsch:0.2.4
     |    \--- com.jcraft:jsch.agentproxy.core:0.0.9
     +--- com.jcraft:jsch.agentproxy.sshagent:0.0.9
     |    \--- com.jcraft:jsch.agentproxy.core:0.0.9
     +--- com.jcraft:jsch.agentproxy.pageant:0.0.9
     |    +--- com.jcraft:jsch.agentproxy.core:0.0.9
     |    +--- net.java.dev.jna:jna:4.1.0
     |    \--- net.java.dev.jna:jna-platform:4.1.0
     |         \--- net.java.dev.jna:jna:4.1.0
     +--- com.jcraft:jsch.agentproxy.usocket-jna:0.0.9
     |    +--- com.jcraft:jsch.agentproxy.core:0.0.9
     |    +--- net.java.dev.jna:jna:4.1.0
     |    \--- net.java.dev.jna:jna-platform:4.1.0 (*)
     +--- com.jcraft:jsch.agentproxy.usocket-nc:0.0.9
     |    \--- com.jcraft:jsch.agentproxy.core:0.0.9
     +--- com.github.zafarkhaja:java-semver:0.9.0
     +--- org.eclipse.jgit:org.eclipse.jgit.ssh.apache:5.13.1.202206130422-r
     |    +--- org.eclipse.jgit:org.eclipse.jgit:5.13.1.202206130422-r (*)
     |    +--- org.apache.sshd:sshd-osgi:2.7.0
     |    |    +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.30
     |    |    \--- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:1.7.30
     |    |         \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.30
     |    +--- org.apache.sshd:sshd-sftp:2.7.0
     |    |    +--- org.apache.sshd:sshd-core:2.7.0
     |    |    |    +--- org.apache.sshd:sshd-common:2.7.0
     |    |    |    |    +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.30
     |    |    |    |    \--- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:1.7.30 (*)
     |    |    |    +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.30
     |    |    |    \--- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:1.7.30 (*)
     |    |    +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.30
     |    |    \--- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:1.7.30 (*)
     |    +--- net.i2p.crypto:eddsa:0.3.0
     |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.30
     +--- org.eclipse.jgit:org.eclipse.jgit.ui:5.13.1.202206130422-r
     |    \--- org.eclipse.jgit:org.eclipse.jgit:5.13.1.202206130422-r (*)
     \--- org.eclipse.jgit:org.eclipse.jgit.gpg.bc:5.13.1.202206130422-r
          +--- org.eclipse.jgit:org.eclipse.jgit:5.13.1.202206130422-r (*)
          +--- org.bouncycastle:bcpg-jdk15on:1.69
          |    \--- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:1.69
          +--- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:1.69
          +--- org.bouncycastle:bcutil-jdk15on:1.69
          |    \--- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:1.69
          +--- org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:1.69
          |    +--- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:1.69
          |    \--- org.bouncycastle:bcutil-jdk15on:1.69 (*)
          \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.30
```

btw, the transitive dependency comes with jGit, and there was an issue using the fork at https://github.com/mwiede/jsch/issues/85, but it's solved now.

Comment: Looks like the dependencies block can be omitted.  You just need the configurations.all{...} content, right?  The plugin is listed in plugins{...}

Comment: Looks like this broke between Gradle 8.2.1  and 8.3.

Comment: https://discuss.gradle.org/t/dependencysubstitutions-regression-in-8-3/47250